# Using Policy Based design C++

Tags: c++, policy-based-design

My present class design is something like this (I have replicated the class hierarchy and function calls.):

```
  Helper* HelperFactory::create(const Advice& advice, const Handler& ah)
  {
       Helper* result = 0;
      switch(advice.getType())
      {
         case ONE:
         case TWO:
        {
                 if(advice.isTradeAdvice())
                      result = new SimpleHedgeHelper(advice, ah);
                 else
                     result = new SimpletradeHelper(advice, ah);
                break;
        } 
        case THREE
        case FOUR:
        case FIVE:
        {
             if(advice.isTradeAdvice())
                    result = new ComplexTradeHelper(advice, ah);
             else
                 result = new ComplexHedgeHelper(advice, ah);
            break;
        }
        case SIX:
        {
            if(!advice.getMsgID())
            {
                if(advice.isTradeAdvice())
                     result = new SimpleTradeHelper(advice, ah);
                else
                     result = new SimpleHedgeHelper(advice, ah);
            break;
             }
            else
             {
                   if(advice.isTradeAdvice())
                      result = new ComplexRateHelper(advice, ah);
                   else
                      result = new ComplexHedgeHelper(advice, ah);
                   break;
              }
       }
  }
```

I am trying to replace this logic with some templated policy based factory. I have not designed any classes earlier based on plicly Can some one please suggest How design should be?

Comment: [OT]: Better to return `std::unique_ptr<Helper>`.

Comment: @TemplateRex have a coffee and reconsider ;)

Comment: @Quentin ah, my bad, those damned CamelCase names.

Answer (score 0):

In considering a move to policy templates, you should evaluate whether the behavioural differences between your current classes can be factored using this kind of approach:

```
template <class Complexity_Policy, class Instrument_Policy>
class Helper : public Abstract_Helper
{
    // for any function Helper needs...
    virtual return_type f(arguments)
    {
         ...can reference Complexity_Policy and/or Instrument_Policy members for behaviours...
    }
};
```

That tends to work best when the behaviours are largely orthogonal (unrelated / decoupled).

If all your client code wants to continue to use run-time polymorphism you will still need your factory, but it should begin returning things like:

```
result = new Helper<Complexity_Policy__Simple, Instrument_Policy__Hendge>(advice, ah);
```

(Yes, I do know the Standard reserves use of double underscores in identifiers... I do accept the risk that this will have undefined behaviour, feeling the only imaginable use of double underscores the implementation may make is as prefixes or suffixes....  Not interested in side-tracking this Q to discuss further.).

You can make selective direct use of the template instantiations too.  Another option is to not even have `Helper` derive from any base or have virtual functions, instead layering runtime polymorphism on top using an `Abstract_Helper* get_polymorphic_accessor()` member that creates a pointer-holding class derived from `Helper` that forwards calls/results.

Comment: Thanks Tony for a quick reply. But refactoring present class Hierarchy is not an option for me :( I was looking for some solution after which   I should be able to get right object by just passing "type" which is an Enum value in my case something like Factort<Type::ONE, dvice.getType()> f; f.create();

Comment: @user1545583: that doesn't sound at all useful, as you'll need each enumeration to be a compile-time constant in every context where you create such a `f` variable, which basically means your current factory's `switch`/`if`/`else` chain just to create a `Factort<...>` variable and use it to indirectly call `new`....